# El exportador de la biblioteca de tipos detectó una instancia de tipo genérico en una signatura

Tags: c#, vb6

Estoy armando una **DLL InteropServices** en **C#** para consumirla desde **VB6**, la única manera que conseguí para poder enviar un `array` de objeto (CodigoDescripcionesString) es crear una clase y heredarla de `IList`, pero cuando quiero registrar la `DLL` en el sistema destino me devuelve el siguiente error:

> El exportador de la biblioteca de tipos detectó una advertencia al procesar 'FECredService.Modelos.Colecciones.CodigosDescripcionesString.GetEnumerator(#0), FECredService'. Advertencia: El exportador de la biblioteca de tipos detectó una instancia de tipo genérico en una signatura. Es posible que el código genérico no se exporte a COM.

Muchas gracias!

**clase CodigosDescripcionesString:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace FECredService.Modelos.Colecciones
{

    [Guid("CEFBAA82-D87D-4710-A98F-20CC3AB30F01")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ProgId("Fce.Colecciones.CodigosDescripcionesString")]

    public class CodigosDescripcionesString : IList<CodigoDescripcionString>
    {
        private List<CodigoDescripcionString> _parts;

        public CodigosDescripcionesString()
        {
            _parts = new List<CodigoDescripcionString>();
        }

        #region IList<CodigoDescripcionString> Members

        public int IndexOf(CodigoDescripcionString item)
        {
            return _parts.IndexOf(item);
        }

        public void Insert(int index, CodigoDescripcionString item)
        {
            _parts.Insert(index, item);
        }

        public void RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            _parts.RemoveAt(index);
        }

        public CodigoDescripcionString this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return _parts[index];
            }
            set
            {
                _parts[index] = value;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region ICollection<CodigoDescripcionString> Members

        [DispId(1)]
        public void Add(CodigoDescripcionString item)
        {
            if (_parts == null)
            {
                _parts = new List<CodigoDescripcionString>();
            }
            _parts.Add(item);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            _parts.Clear();
        }

        public bool Contains(CodigoDescripcionString item)
        {
            return _parts.Contains(item);
        }

        public void CopyTo(CodigoDescripcionString[] array, int arrayIndex)
        {
            _parts.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return _parts.Count; }
        }

        public bool Remove(CodigoDescripcionString item)
        {
            return _parts.Remove(item);
        }

        #endregion

        #region ICollection<CodigoDescripcionString> Members


        public bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get;
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable<CodigoDescripcionString> Members

        public IEnumerator<CodigoDescripcionString> GetEnumerator()
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            for (int i = 0; i < _parts.Count; i++)
            {
                yield return _parts[i];
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IEnumerable Members

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        #endregion

        [ComVisible(false)]
        public void Cast(Fce.CodigoDescripcionStringType[] p)
        {
            _parts = new List<CodigoDescripcionString>();

            foreach (var i in p)
            {
                CodigoDescripcionString s = new CodigoDescripcionString();

                s.codigo = i.codigo;
                s.descripcion = i.codigo;

                Add(s);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Clase CodigoDescripcionString:**

```
using FECredService.Interface;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace FECredService.Modelos
{


    [Guid("69AB6F29-B66C-4818-A557-8922E02F7C20")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ProgId("Fce.Models.CodigoDescripcionString")]
    public class CodigoDescripcionString : ICodigoDescripcionString
    {
        public CodigoDescripcionString() { }
        public string codigo { get; set; }
        public string descripcion { get; set; }

        [ComVisible(false)]
        public void Cast(Fce.CodigoDescripcionStringType p)
        {
            codigo = p.codigo;
            descripcion = p.descripcion;
        }
    }
}
```